Dictionary mapping via range, use value as output
Hope you can accomodate my question this is all about dictionary key range.
Here's my dictionary pattern
CB = {range(1,16):16,
      range(17,20):20,
      range(21,32):32,
      range(33,40):40}

This is my dataframe
data = {'CL':[0.027, 0.350, 1.15, 3.5],
        'TYP':['LTG', 'CO', 'MTR', 'ACU'],
        'ATS':[0, 0, 0, 0]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I want to update the ATS side that will be base on the dictionary above using the lambda below:
def ATS_szng(x,y):
    if y == 'LTG':
        return 16
    elif y == 'CO':
        return 20
    elif y == 'MTR':
        val = 2.5 * x
        z = lambda a: next((v for k,v in CB.items() if a in k), 0)
        return z(val)
    else:
        val = x * 2.5

df['AT'] = df.apply(lambda row:ATS_szng(row['CL'], row['TYP']), axis =1)

I got this answer of 0, but the answer I needed should be base on the above CB dictionary
enter image description here
To know the answer using dictionary range key with the output values.

Are you even using CB as a dictionary, or are you just accessing it with CB.items()?  If the latter, then you'd be better off making it a list of pairs.  Or else expanding the ranges so that you can use the range elements as actual keys.  What's there now seems like the worst of both worlds.

You're also using floating point for val.  If it happens to be an integer floating point value, then the range check will work, but if it's fractional, then it won't, since the ranges only contain integers.

Hi @TomKarzes actually yes, my apologize. I am new in pandas python. What I want is the value of CB dictionary. in any value of val.

There's no need for the lambda. You can just write return next(...)

a in k won't return the desired result if a is a fraction. Testing for membership in a range acts like the range is a list of integers, it doesn't just check that the number is between the start and end.
As suggested in the comments, it would be better to change your dictionary to a list. And instead of ranges, use start/end values that you can compare with explicitly.
And since the desired value is always the end of the range, there's no need to include that explicitly.
CB = [(1,16),
      (17,20),
      (21,32),
      (33,40)]

Then in your function you can use:
    elif y == 'MTR':
        val = 2.5 * x
        return next((end for start, end in CB if start <= val < end+1), 0)

Note also that I use end+1. Otherwise, if val is something like 16.5 it won't fall in any of the ranges.

I think you're looking for IntervalIndex + pd.cut:
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(
    [1, 16, 20, 32, 40],
    closed="left",
)

df["ATS"] = np.nan
mtr = df.TYP == "MTR"

df.loc[mtr, "ATS"] = [i.right for i in pd.cut(df.loc[mtr, "CL"] * 2.5, bins)]
df.loc[df.TYP == "LTG", "ATS"] = 16
df.loc[df.TYP == "CO", "ATS"] = 20
df.loc[tmp, "ATS"] = df.loc[(tmp := df.ATS.isna()), "CL"] * 2.5

print(df)

Prints:
      CL  TYP    ATS
0  0.027  LTG  16.00
1  0.350   CO  20.00
2  1.150  MTR  16.00
3  3.500  ACU   8.75

